# Unexplained Redish Tint on Transparent Texture in EEVEE

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I have a transparent plane with an also transparent texture on it. My problem is that from certain angles, a reddish tint appears on the edge of the texture, and I cannot explain how it got there. Can anyone help me explain what it is and how to get rid of it?

I put every relevant information onto this screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I believe that is an issue with the actual image.

Comment: I thought so too, but checked the image and it has no red aside from the lower right part. You can actually see it on the image where I show the texture in the UV editor. Also, it renders perfectly fine in Cycles.

Comment: Add a mapping node.Texture coordinate to mapping if not then the issue maybe with EEVEE.